# HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion() in spring MVC changes response code

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jetty, spring-boot

I am using spring MVC framework. I want to log error statuses whenever exception is thrown, so `afterCompletion` method is used in `HanlderInterceptor`.

```
@Override
public void afterCompletion( final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler, final Exception ex)
{
    final int responseCode = response.getStatus();
    s_logger_error.error("status code: " + responseCode );
}
```

This code works fine if I run this as an application on local machine. But when we host it on the jetty server, UI gets correct error response (In my case `409`), but in this method it gets logged as `200`.

[Image from remote debug where it shows `status=200` but in response it is `409`] 
[image]

Can somebody help to figure out why there is change in the response code?

I am using sprint 1.1.7.RELEASE spring boot version and jetty-distribution-9.2.10.v20150310.

Comment: Where is 409 status code set? It's possible that it's set after your HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion()

Comment: 409 status is set before HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion() is called.

Comment: Did you implement `HandlerInterceptor` or subclass one of the implementations?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you call `setStatus` method on your `response` object on exception.

If you assert this, than upgrading to spring boot version 1.1.11 can fix your issue. It concerns this [fix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2367). Prior to the fix, the `ErrorPageFilter` was masking the response status of wrapped response in the cases where `sendError` method is not explicitely called on the `ErrorWrapperResponse`.

The code after the fixed [changed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/b3597107bab903d3c0012d0279a240aeefe6e25b) from simple `return this.status` to

```
        if (this.errorToSend) {
            return this.status;
        }
        else {
            // If there was no error we need to trust the wrapped response
            return super.getStatus();
        }
```

that is why I believe that the upgrade will fix your issue.

Finally, if you issue persist, debugging through [`ErrorPageFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/b3597107bab903d3c0012d0279a240aeefe6e25b/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/web/ErrorPageFilter.java) should indicate the origin of the problem